# Google Maps Android v2 on devices with no openGL ES2

Tags: android, google-maps, opengl-es

I'm trying to do a simple app with a map... I've follow [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/google-maps-in-android-application-with-new-google-maps-android-api-v2-using-supportmapfragment/) example and manage to do the app. Also need to add this to the manifiest:

```
<meta-data 
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

The problem is I get a blank screen on my Motorola CilqXT but runs fine on a Galaxy Fame.

I'm guessing the problem maybe that my CliqXT doesn't support openGL 2.

So my question is how can I develop and app with just a map for my device?

Other applications as EasyTaxi, Netmonitor and a lot more, works fine on my phone, so I guess there must be something I can do.

**EDIT**

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.locationgooglemapv2demo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="7"
    android:maxSdkVersion="17"/>


<permission
    android:name="com.example.locationgooglemapv2demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.locationgooglemapv2demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<!-- Requerir openGL ES 2.0 si el cel no lo tiene no la ven en el market -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.locationgooglemapv2demo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

    <!-- ESTO ES NECESARIO PORQUE UTILIZA GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my_API_key"/>

</application>
```

**CODE**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Thanks again

---

**EDIT**

Sadly I've got to say that I think it's impossible to run google maps android api v2 on a device with no openGL ES2.0 support. And sadly, my Cliq XT doesn't support it.

Thank you all for helping me!!
Best Regards!

Comment: post your code and log

Comment: post your manifest.xml

Comment: The strange thig is that it works on other deveices but not on mine

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this in your manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" 
 android:required="true"/>
```

Comment: Yes I did... I read about it and I think that was to requiere the app to use openGL ES 2.0, if the app were in the market the devices with no openGL ES 2.0 will not be able to see the app because it's not compatible with them. I''l edit my post and put code and manifest